# Ruby on Rails mysql migrate use Timezone instead of Datetime

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, datetime, ruby-on-rails-4, timestamp

I am keeping in my mysql table a column called

> starts_at

my column can be with a different timezone each time.

I have tried creating a migration:

```
def self.up
    create_table :meetings, id: false, force: true do |t|
         t.string       :id
         t.timestamp    :starts_at
    end
end
```

but i always end up with a

> datetime

column type

i want to force rails to use `timestamp`, and tried all of these with **with no success**:

```
def up
    change_column :meetings, :starts_at, :timestamp
end
```

this:

```
def up
    change_column :meetings, :starts_at, 'timestamp'
end
```

and this:

```
 def self.up
    create_table :meetings, id: false, force: true do |t|
         t.string       :id
         t.column       :starts_at, 'timestamp'
    end
end
```

any ideas?

**update:**

> i want to save the timezone on the database record and not on the
>   application configuration

Answer (score 0):

Rails actually makes some of decisions for you. Both `:timestamp` and `:datetime` will default to `DATETIME`, while `:date` and `:time` corresponds to `DATE` and `TIME`, respectively.

Using Rails, you only have to decide whether you need to store date, time or both.

So you can use type `:datetime` in your `:starts_at` column.

Comment: but then it saves my timezone as utc, and the current timezone i need..?
(i use many timezones for the :starts_at column)

Comment: If you want to save time with specific timezone, then set the `Time.zone` at application level, for example you want to save time in "Eastern Time (US & Canada)" then you have to define zone in your application level as
`Time.zone = "Eastern Time (US & Canada)"`
So by this you can save your time according to your specific zone, and when you will see the time in database it will be in utc format because in database it store by default in utc format, but when you will use that time in your application e.g `meetings.starts_at`, it will convert the time to your default time zone.

Comment: Now I understand your problem, in my opinion you just add another column in database as timezone, and in every starts_at column you will also save timezone of that time, so by this you can use that timezone wherever you will use the time, e.g
`Time.zone = meetings.timezone`
`meetings.starts_at` -> this will use the timezone which is saved with starts_at time.

Comment: do you know if the `starts_at` looks for a `timezone` column automatically? or after each load i need to modify the the timezone?
also, how does a save happen? do i need to specify the `timezone` when i save, or it does it by itself?

Answer (score 0):

Look at this example in config/application.rb

```
class Application < Rails::Application
   config.time_zone = 'Sydney'
   config.time_zone = 'Kuala Lumpur'
   config.active_record.default_timezone = 'Kuala Lumpur'
end
```

You can set your Time zone according to requirement and you can make it dynamic.

Here is all timezone `ActiveSupport::TimeZone.all.map(&:name)`

Comment: what if i want to save the timezone on the database instead (and not to configure it on the application)?